# mySQL: Quering time-related rows grouped by century?

Tags: mysql, time, rdbms

I am working on a project which features one database table looking like this (structurally, but not datawise - puuh):

```
year    |  event                               |    category
------------------------------------------------------------
1970    |  Someone ate a cheeseburger          |   food
2010    |  Justin bieber was discovered        |   other
1500    |  Columbus makes 3rd trip to America  |   notable
------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I query this table, so that my result is grouped in a per-century way?

> 2000-century:
>   2010 - Justin bieber was discovered
>
> 1900-century:
>   1970 - Someone ate a cheeseburger
>
> 1500-century:
>   1500 - Columbus makes 3rd trip to America

Sorry for the cheesy psuedodata :)

Comment: Hmm group by the 1st two digits of `year` (sorry, I don't have actual code on hand for MySQL to do this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a century function, but it does have year, so you basically do:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM yourtable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY CAST((Year(datetimefield) / 100) AS INTEGER)
```

Of course, this doesn't take into account that centuries officially start on their year "1", and not on the year "0" (e.g. 1900 is still the 18th century, not 19th). But if you're not a stickler for precision, the simple "divide by 100" method is the quickest/easiest.

Comment: Hi Marc.  `AS INTEGER`.. isn't valid, but `(CAST( FLOOR( (year / 100) ) AS UNSIGNED))` work well. May help someone else. Late thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST((Year(datetimefield) / 100) AS INTEGER) as century, someotherfields
FROM yourtable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY datetimefield
```

Is a better aproach to the question I think.

(pseudo code borrowed from Marc B)